# Скрипт для проверки

Tags: php, нагрузочное-тестирование

Нужно тестировать модуль онлайна на сайте.
Для этого при вводе URL адреса сайта в скрипте, чтобы рандомно показовались IP, UA и т.д. То есть, как бы боты-пользователи.

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Для тестирования подобного функционала хорошо подходят инструменты для нагрузочного тестирования. Посмотрите в сторону Яндекс.Танк https://tech.yandex.ru/tank/ и jMeter.